# IdentityServer4 accessibility via both front-channel and back-channel URL

Tags: identityserver4

Some networks are configured so that trusted clients and resource providers access IdP via *back-channel* URL (e.g. http://idp.mycorp.local), while public clients like SPAs access it via *front-channel* URL (e.g. https://idp.mycorp.com).

Which is the ideal solution for such a network configuration?

We have been experiencing with the following options:

1. Populate some endpoints (authorization_endpoint, end_session_endpoint) in the discovery document with the front-channel host name regardless of which host name was used for requesting the document;
2. Configure trusted clients to access IdP via back-channel URL, but switch to using the front-channel URL when it is going to redirect the user agent to IdP.